# What Happens to Gmail Labels After Migration to Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, gmail

What happens to the messages in Gmail that have had a label applied to them when migrated from Gmail to Office 365?  Do they get moved into separate folders based on the label or are they dumped into the inbox to be sorted manually later?  Does anyone know or can point me to a resource that does?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on Software and Settings which are set. The most case is that the Labels become converted into Folders. [Quest](https://www.quest.com/products/on-demand-migration-for-email/) you find it @features / Label conversion.

Comment: No software.  We're following Microsoft's steps for a Gmail IMAP migration.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: ok, n.p.:
[Office365 Step by Step migration](https://portal.office.com/onboarding/GmailIMAPMigration#/)
after login you find a step by step go threw for google mail migration with everything you need to know (incl. Labels)

Comment: Using the default Microsoft migration method, no 3rd party tools or tricks, created a new folder to represent each of the labels.  Exactly as you stated Pawel. One gotcha to consider though is that if the message has multiple labels it will be duplicated between the new folders.